# how to placer asterisks by required field plus jquery validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-validate

I am wondering how I would place an asterisk by a required field and also have the jquery validation message also there.  I am a complete noob at jquery so I am kind of confused about how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what can sum it up

**first part:**
How to implement asterix by required field

**Option1:**
define asterix in display name

```
[DisplayName("User Name *")]  //this will be defined in entity or model
<%= Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Name) %> //access data
```

**Option 2:** 
using label and add manually span with asterix

```
[DisplayName("User Name")]
<%= Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Name) %><span>*</span>
```

**for second part( validation using jquery)**
check this link it is guide how to implement client side validation using jquery:

```
http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/03/21/mvc-2-jquery-client-side-validation.aspx
```